# Custom sort array of hashes based on multiple key/value pairs

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have an array of hashes which I need to sort based on two different key value pairs.

Here is the array I am trying to sort:

```
array_group =  [
 {operator: OR, name: "some string", status: false},
 {operator: AND, name: "other string", status: false},
 {operator: _NOT_PRESENT, name: "another string", status: true},
 {operator: AND, name: "just string", status: true}
]
```

I want to sort `array_group` so I have items with `status: true` first, followed by `status: false`, followed by the items with `operator: _NOT_PRESENT` and finally sort it based on name, resulting in something like:

```
array_group = [
 {operator: AND, name: "just string", status: true},
 {operator: AND, name: "other string", status: false},
 {operator: OR, name: "some string", status: false},
 {operator: _NOT_PRESENT, name: "another string", status: true},
]
```

Is there a way that I can get this done without creating sub-arrays and sorting them and concatenating them back?

Comment: The statement of your question suggests that `status` can have a value other than `True` or `False`. Is that correct?

Comment: yes status is not actually a boolean its a string which I am later wrapping to boolean values if it has true or false in some other part of code

Comment: How did `"other string"`'s `status` switch from `true` to `false`? Why is `"another string"` not first in the sorted array, consider that it ties with `"other string"` on the value of `:status` and is the only one of the two to have  `_NOT_PRESENT` as the value of `:operator`?

Comment: You gave us data, but no code. Are you asking us to write the code for you?

Comment: @CarySwoveland since I did not copy the array data from code I miss wrote the result array when I formatted this question, sorry about that, reagarding the _NOT_PRESENT - what ever the name string or status be if the item has the operator _NOT_PRESENT then it should end up being at the bottom of the sorted array

Comment: @theTinMan I am not asking for code I tried few things which actually resembles few answers over here and I also tried things like splitting these into three arrays sorting them and concatenating them back as I mentioned in question, but I want suggestions on that approach and also wanted to know if it can be achieved in more optimized way because I know ruby has lot of convince method and since I am new to ruby I am unaware of lot of them :)

Comment: In that case you need to edit the question and correct the statement of the desired ordering. You should leave the current statement and then add something like "Edit: this statement is not correct ect. It should read:...". If you merely replace the current statement it would render comments and answers meaningless and puzzling. Also correct your desired result (array).

Comment: But don't use "Edit:" or "Update:". We can tell when those have occurred and see what changed if necessary. Instead, simply add the needed information into the question as if it was originally added. A question is a preface to a reference page on solving the question, so write like it's an article for future people reading it.

Comment: And while those things might have been done, we'll waste our time suggesting things you've already tried and rejected unless you tell us. Help us help you by reducing the possible things to try.

Comment: @theTinMan & Cary Swoveland thank you for the above suggestion, I will keep in mind such things next time I post a question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by). The example builds an array which is compared element by element when sorting.

```
array_group.sort_by { |e| [e[:operator] == "_NOT_PRESENT" ? 1 : 0, 
                           e[:status] ? 0 : 1, 
                           e[:name]] }
```

The example above orders records with `operator: "_NOT_PRESENT"` also by `:status`. The following snippet precisely performs the ordering from the question.

```
def priority(h)
  case
  when h[:operator] == "_NOT_PRESENT" then 3
  when h[:status] == false            then 2
  # h[:status] == true
  else 1
  end
end

array_group.sort_by { |e| [priority(e), e[:name]] }
```

Comment: If embedded in a method this will not work because `_NOT_PRESENT` is a local variable. If you change `_NOT_PRESENT` to `NOT_PRESENT`, both here and in `array_group`,  after having defined the constant `NOT_PRESENT`, you get `{:operator=>"and", :name=>"just string", :status=>true}` as the first element of the sorted array, which is incorrect.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The first element you mention is the first element of the desired result. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Your first line puts "another string" after all other hashes (regardless of the value of `:status`, which is the first filter). Suppose `:status=true` for "another string" (as it is now), but `:status=false` for all other hashes. Then "another string" should be sorted first, not last.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I understand the question in another way. 
1st place ordering is `[status: true, status: false, operator: _NOT_DEFINED]`, 2nd is sorted by `:name`. That's what the desired result looks like.

Comment: @sschmeck you are right about the order of array items i.e., status: true comes first (all status true items are further sorted by name) then comes status false (all status false items further sorted by name) and then finally status _NOT_PRESENT will be present :) this answer works for me but I am trying few more scenarios before I accept it ,,, thank you for your answer

Comment: @jay What kind of value represents `_NOT_PRESENT`? Like mentioned by @CarySwoveland the underscore makes it a local variable and therefore it can't be used outside the current scope.

Comment: @sschmeck I am working with an API which returns an array of such objects (as mentioned in question) for some reason they are sending the value of the key 'operator' as _NOT_PRESENT if it is not AND or OR (the logic which assigns operator is inside the API and I have not control over it)

Comment: @jay What type/class is `_NOT_PRESENT`?

Comment: @sschmeck _NOT_PRESENT is a string .. the operator 'key' in hash is assigned something like operator:'_NOT_PRESENT' or operator: 'AND' or operator:'OR'...

Comment: @jay I updated my answer and added a solution that only sorts like you defined it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Array.sort` method. It accepts a block with two arguments (x, y), when x is larger than y it should return 1, otherwise -1, and 0 if they are equal.

The code:

```
OR = "OR"
AND = "AND"
_NOT_PRESENT = "_NOT_PRESENT"

array_group =  [
 {operator: OR, name: "some string", status: false},
 {operator: AND, name: "other string", status: true},
 {operator: _NOT_PRESENT, name: "another string", status: true},
 {operator: AND, name: "just string", status: true}
]

results = array_group.sort do |x, y|
  next x[:operator] == _NOT_PRESENT ? 1 : -1 if x[:operator] == _NOT_PRESENT || y[:operator] == _NOT_PRESENT
  next x[:status] ? -1 : 1 if x[:status] != y[:status]
  next x[:name] <=> y[:name]
end
```

And btw, you your input and output data doesn't match each other — the hash with OR is `false` in the input, but `true` in the output.

I believe your output should look like:

```
[{:operator=>"AND", :name=>"just string", :status=>true},
 {:operator=>"AND", :name=>"other string", :status=>true},
 {:operator=>"OR", :name=>"some string", :status=>false},
 {:operator=>"_NOT_PRESENT", :name=>"another string", :status=>true}]
```

That output will actually match your sorting logic.

Comment: thank you for the answer,,, sorry for presenting wrong info,,, it was a typo regarding one entry but my final output should always  have _NOT_PRESENT at the last..

Comment: I've added another version, so _NOT_PRESENTs are always last, otherwise status == true goes before status == false, when statuses are equal then names are compared alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the unspecified constants `OR`, `AND` and `NOT_PRESENT` are defined as follows (for example):

```
OR = "or"
AND = "and"
NOT_PRESENT = "not present"
```

(Constants must begin with a capital letter. `_NOT_PRESENT` is a local variable.)

When using [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), you need to sort on an array containing three elements, corresponding to `:status`, `:operator` and `:name`, in that order. The first of those three elements is smallest (say `0`) if the value of `:status` is `true`, next smallest (say `1`) if the value of `:status` is `false` and largest (say `2`) if it is anything else. We have:

```
def rearrange(arr)
  arr.sort_by do |h|
    [
      h[:status]==true ? 0 : (h[:status]==false ? 1 : 2),
      (h[:operator]==NOT_PRESENT) ? 0 : 1, 
      h[:name]
    ]
  end
end

array_group = [
 {operator: AND, name: "just string", status: true},
 {operator: OR, name: "some string", status: false},
 {operator: AND, name: "other string", status: false},
 {operator: NOT_PRESENT, name: "another string", status: true},
]

rearrange(array_group)
  #=> [{:operator=>"not present", :name=>"another string", :status=>true},
  #    {:operator=>"and", :name=>"just string", :status=>true},
  #    {:operator=>"and", :name=>"other string", :status=>false}, 
  #    {:operator=>"or", :name=>"some string", :status=>false}]
```

This is not the result desired, but it is consistent with my understanding of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) using an array to keep the groups you want and sorting by name without lose those groups.
For example:

```
[[0,0,1], [1,1,1], [0,1,0], [1,0,0], [0,1,1]].sort_by &:itself
# => [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Using this, you can set an array with length 2. Using index 0 to "group" by the elements you want and index 1 to sort by name.

```
OR = "OR"
AND = "AND"
_NOT_PRESENT = "_NOT_PRESENT"

array_group =  [
 { operator: OR, name: "z string", status: false },
 { operator: AND, name: "a string", status: false },
 { operator: AND, name: "z string", status: true },
 { operator: OR, name: "a string", status: true },
 { operator: _NOT_PRESENT, name: "d string", status: true },
 { operator: _NOT_PRESENT, name: "b string", status: true },
 { operator: _NOT_PRESENT, name: "c string", status: false },
 { operator: _NOT_PRESENT, name: "a string", status: false }
]

# Types of "groups" you want to keep. Greater values will be at the end
BY_NOT_PRESENT = 2
BY_STATUS_FALSE = 1
BY_STATUS_TRUE = 0

array_group.sort_by do |a|
  group = if a[:operator] == _NOT_PRESENT
            BY_NOT_PRESENT
          else
            a[:status] ? BY_STATUS_TRUE : BY_STATUS_FALSE
          end
  [group, a[:name]]
end
#=> [{:operator=>"OR", :name=>"a string", :status=>true},
#     {:operator=>"AND", :name=>"z string", :status=>true},
#     {:operator=>"AND", :name=>"a string", :status=>false}, 
#     {:operator=>"OR", :name=>"z string", :status=>false}, 
#     {:operator=>"_NOT_PRESENT", :name=>"a string", :status=>false}, 
#     {:operator=>"_NOT_PRESENT", :name=>"b string", :status=>true}, 
#     {:operator=>"_NOT_PRESENT", :name=>"c string", :status=>false}, 
#     {:operator=>"_NOT_PRESENT", :name=>"d string", :status=>true}]
```

I am doing this way, because if just sort_by an array like `[status, not_present, name]` then `status` will have precedence on sort, overriding the `name` sort, resulting this:

```
#=> [{:operator=>"OR", :name=>"a string", :status=>true}, 
#    {:operator=>"AND", :name=>"z string", :status=>true}, 
#    {:operator=>"AND", :name=>"a string", :status=>false}, 
#    {:operator=>"OR", :name=>"z string", :status=>false}, 
#    {:operator=>"_NOT_PRESENT", :name=>"b string", :status=>true}, 
#    {:operator=>"_NOT_PRESENT", :name=>"d string", :status=>true}, 
#    {:operator=>"_NOT_PRESENT", :name=>"a string", :status=>false}, 
#    {:operator=>"_NOT_PRESENT", :name=>"c string", :status=>false}]
```